# IIS 10 send client ip as response header

Tags: iis, server

So, this problem has recently cropped up. I have an application that has been running for many years. The application is a RAD Studio C++ based web server application. In the application, I check the client's IP Address via `Request->RemoteAddr`. Suddenly (could be from a MS update) the `RemoteAddr` value is now the server's IP address instead of the client.

Is there a work-around or a fix for this?

Comment: Could you fix this issue by rolling back any update? This issue just looks like a proxy server has been set up on your server. So every time client send request, you will only see the server's Ip address in Remote_Addr variable.

Comment: Possibly, but I don't know which update caused the issue. Additionally, some other update apparently cleared the issue.